# Pygame - Mouse clicks not getting detected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm learning Pygame to make games w/ Python. However, I'm encountering a problem. I'm trying to detect when the player is currently clicking the screen, but my code isn't working. Is my code actually screwed, or is it just the online Pygame compiler that I'm using?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))

while True:
  pygame.display.update()
  mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
  if mouse:
    print("You are clicking")
  else:
    print("You released")
```

When I ran this code, the output console spammed the text "You are clicking", thousands of times in a second. Even when I'm not clicking the screen, it still says this. Even when my mouse isn't **over** the screen. Just the same text. Over, and over. Is Pygame executing my program correctly?

To learn Pygame, I am using the official Docs from the developers. https://www.pygame.org/docs/ Is this an outdated way to learn, is this why my code continues to run errors?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. How come you can run my code and it works perfectly fine.... But when i run it, errors appear? Did you change the code? Adjust anything?

Comment: Except if condition first try to print(mouse).

Comment: When i do print(mouse), it works perfectly fine and prints the coordinates.

Comment: Nevermind, @Rabbid76 solved my problem. Really smart guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates which are returned by [`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) are evaluated when the events are handled. You need to handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).

See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

[`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) returns a sequence of booleans representing the state of all the mouse buttons. Hense you have to evaluate if [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) button is pressed (`any(buttons)`) or if a special button is pressed by subscription (e.g. `buttons[0]`).

For instance:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
  
    buttons = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    # if buttons[0]:  # for the left mouse button
    if any(buttons):  # for any mouse button
        print("You are clicking")
    else:
        print("You released")

    pygame.display.update()
```

---

If you just want to detect when the mouse button is pressed respectively released, then you have to implement the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` and `MOUSEBUTTONUP` (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module):

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print("You are clicking", event.button)
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            print("You released", event.button)

    pygame.display.update()
```

---

While `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` returns the current state of the buttons, the  `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` and `MOUSEBUTTONUP` occurs only once a button is pressed.

Comment: @Binji [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) checks if any element of a list is true.

Comment: Using any it it detects both left click and right click check out my answer

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer Question: *"I'm trying to detect when the player is currently clicking the screen"* - the questioner doesn't specify the which button, so `any` is a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The function pygame.mouse.get_pressed returns a list which contains true or false so for single click u should use-

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
  pygame.display.update()
  mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
  if mouse[0]:
    print("You are clicking")
  else:
    print("You released")
```

Comment: See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get):

"*For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system."*. Without event handling ` pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` won't return anything.